# What would my DC meter on my digital multimeter measure if I was scoping a digital signal?

Tags: multimeter

If I measure an AC voltage it shows 0 Volts. If for example I have a rectangular pulse from 0 to 5 V with 25% duty cycle the meter will show 1.25 volts?

Comment: A meter that reads DC voltage **should** display the percentage of the supply voltage that represents the duty cycle.

Comment: This also depends on the meter.  Some do true RMS (Root-Mean-Square) calculation, some don't, and a select few lie about being able to do it.

Comment: That depends on how slow or fast the PWM frequency is and how slow or fast is the meter response time.

Answer (score 2):

Any meter with a continuous-time input will measure the *average* voltage, i.e. 1.25 V.

A meter with discrete-time - aka sample & hold - input will usually measure either 5 V or 0V. But often a meter averages many such readings to extend resolution by oversampling. If the meter is not clocked from the same source as the PWM creator (it is *asynchronous*), you will measure the average voltage, provided the integration time is much longer than the PWM and sampling periods.

The only way to obtain a non-average value even after substantial oversampling is with a synchronously clocked sample-and-hold input meter.